# ConfigurationErrorsException thrown when unrelated address fails

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5

I have two services setup.  Service1 works fine.  Service2 has a bad address.  Why is it that when I try to call Service1 it fails with an error:

`the value of the property 'address' cannot be parsed`

If I fix the bad address on Service2 then things start working again.  I would expect Service1 to continue to function even if Service2 is broken.

**Code**

```
            try
            {
                var client = new FooWurldClient();
                Console.WriteLine(client.DoWork());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
;

            try
            {
                var client2 = new HelloWorldService.HelloWorldClient();
                Console.WriteLine(client2.DoWork());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

**Config**

Bad address

`<endpoint address="http://localhost:631562222/BadService.svc"`

Note that even if I comment out client2 (bad service) code, client1 (good service) fails.

Answer (score 0):

The parser is somehow smart enough to recognize that the port is higher than the maximum ephemeral port of 65535.  I lowered the port number to some random invalid port number in range and the failure went away.

Still surprising to see this.

Answer (score 0):

The run time read the configuration before the launch of your application codes. And the reading got an exception thrown because of the bad address, not caught in a place you would expect, say soon after the endpoint line, resulting in the whole reading failing; so all services were failing.

If you assign the bad addresses in your application codes, likely through common design the error of the bad port number could be isolated.

Nevertheless, I do consider that bad port exceeding the boundary in config is a critical error, essentially is of malformed XML or nonconforming schema, against which the run time should fail the launch of all services. For such regards, the run time is consistent.